# Unexpected output containing plus, minus, and letters produced by subtracting one column of numbers from another in R

Tags: r, subtraction, bandpass-filter

I have a data.frame containing a vector of numeric values (prcp_log).

```
  waterdate  PRCP prcp_log
  <date>     <dbl>    <dbl>
1 2007-10-01  0      0     
2 2007-10-02  0.02   0.0198
3 2007-10-03  0.31   0.270 
4 2007-10-04  1.8    1.03  
5 2007-10-05  0.03   0.0296
6 2007-10-06  0.19   0.174
```

I then pass this data through Christiano-Fitzgerald band pass filter using the following command from the mfilter package.

```
library(mFilter)

US1ORLA0076_cffilter  <- cffilter(US1ORLA0076$prcp_log,pl=180,pu=365,root=FALSE,drift=FALSE,
                                  type=c("asymmetric"),
                                  nfix=NULL,theta=1)
```

Which creates an S3 object containing, among other things, and vector of "trend" values and a vector of "cycle" values, like so:

```
head(US1ORLA0076_cffilter$trend)
           [,1]
[1,] 0.05439408
[2,] 0.07275321
[3,] 0.32150292
[4,] 1.07958965
[5,] 0.07799329
[6,] 0.22082246

head(US1ORLA0076_cffilter$cycle)
            [,1]
[1,] -0.05439408
[2,] -0.05295058
[3,] -0.05147578
[4,] -0.04997023
[5,] -0.04843449
[6,] -0.04686915
```

Plotted:

```
plot(US1ORLA0076_cffilter)
```

[image]

I then apply the following mathematical operation in attempt to remove the trend and seasonal components from the original numeric vector:

```
US1ORLA0076$decomp <- ((US1ORLA0076$prcp_log - US1ORLA0076_cffilter$trend) - US1ORLA0076_cffilter$cycle)
```

Which creates an output of values which includes unexpected elements such as dashes and letters.

```
head(US1ORLA0076$decomp)
              [,1]
[1,]  0.000000e+00
[2,]  0.000000e+00
[3,]  1.387779e-17
[4,] -2.775558e-17
[5,]  0.000000e+00
[6,]  6.938894e-18
```

What has happened here? What do these additional characters signify? How can perform this mathematical operation and achieve the desired output  of simply $log_prcp minus both the $tend and $cycle values?

I am happy to provide any additional info that will help right away, just ask.

Comment: This is scientific notation. To turn it off use options(scipen = 999)

Comment: Are you referring to the `"e-" and "e+"`? They are the exponent form. You can take it to mean "10 to the power of"

Comment: Is the meaning and usage of this notation in R documented somewhere where I can read more about it? What is it called / what should I search for? @HarroCyranka

Comment: These `decomp` figures are so tiny that I suspect your filter is overfitting and your trend is capturing the signal AND the noise, so that there's only a floating point rounding error left, in the 17th or 18th decimal place.

Comment: I found this website that may be valuable:
https://www.burns-stat.com/documents/tutorials/impatient-r/more-r-key-objects/more-r-numbers/

Comment: @JonSpring I've added a plot of the filter for assessment. A visual inspection seems to suggest that the cycle is appropriately capturing the annual seasonality of the data, but I am very interested to hear if you disagree. However, I am quite confused why the trend is so high resolution, as I would expect a smooth-ish trend line. Thoughts?

Comment: Not my area of expertise, but this looks backwards to me. I would have thought the trend plot would be much smoother, leaving a bumpy residual "cycle," like in the examples here: https://rdrr.io/cran/mFilter/man/cffilter.html   I wonder if `pl` should be 2 instead of 180?